# getting exception in ivy:configure task

Tags: ant, teamcity, ivy

I have the following ivy:configure tag inmy build.xml as shown

```
<target name="prepare" description="Ivy setting load">
            <echo message="Saral in Prepare"/>
            <delete dir="${project_dependencies}"/>
            <mkdir dir="${project_dependencies}"/>
            <path id="classpath">
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="${ops.dir}/ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </path>
            <ivy:configure file="${ops.dir}/ivy/ivysettings.xml" />
            <ivy:retrieve  type="jar" pattern="${project_dependencies}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </target>
```

....but upon running the build ,  i am getting the following expection...please advise what mistake i have done in my build.xml

```
[prepare] ivy:configure
[15:37:42]Problem: failed to create task or type ant lib:org.apache.ivy.ant:configure \
    Cause: The name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. \
    Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. \
    Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place. \
    No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet  \
    This appears to be an antlib declaration. \
    Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of: - \
    C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\ant\lib - \
    \\delfiler3.fm.rbsgrp.net\saxensl\MyGEOSProfile\FDR\.ant\lib \
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

in the build.xml I have started as follows..

```
<project name="abc" basedir="../." default="fulldist" 
    xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

<!-- ivy task -->
    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ps.dir}/ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

Comment: How did you define the Ivy tasks via the `<taskdef/>` task?

Did you define _Namespaces_ via the `URI`?

Comment: @DavidW. pls see I have updated the comments and in the last updated snapshot you can see the initial build.xml eneteries

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a NAMESPACE for your Ivy tasks (and that's recommended), you need the URI parameter in the `<taskdef/>`:

```
<project ... 
    xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">  <!-- Declares a namespace "ivy:"        -->

    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">    <!-- This was missing                   -->
                                            <!-- You need that to link your "ivy:"  -->
                                            <!-- Namespace to your XMLNS definition -->
                                            <!-- in the <project/> entity on top    -->
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ps.dir}/ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

The URI field links your Ivy jar tasks with the namespace you declared in your XMLNS parameter on the top of your `build.xml`. For example, you declared an XML Namespace called `ivy` that's associated with the URI `antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant`. Now, you have to use that URI in your `<taskdef/>` to link that `ivy:` namespace with the task definitions.

You don't need to declare a XML namespace, but if you don't instead of `<ivy:configure/>`, you'd use `<configure/>` as the task name. You can see how this could cause problems if you use other third party Ant task libraries. There's a `<report/>` task in Ivy, and it's likely that another third party ant task library will also have a `<report/>` task. By declaring a namespace for your tasks, you eliminate this issue.